# How to separate 2 column in dataframe and save to .csv file

Tags: python, pandas

First of all I have multiple txt files (1000 files) and I will make dataframe from 2 columns.
first column is filename of txt file. and 2nd is data if each text files.

I try to write code as below.

```
import os
import shutil
import pandas as pd
import time
import datetime
import glob
from pathlib import Path
from os import walk

#make df from text
myFiles = glob.glob('C:\\Users\\xxx\\Sub_Folder\\*.txt')

final_df=[]

for item in myFiles:    
    with open(item, 'rt') as fd:
        for first_line in fd.readlines():
            splited = first_line.split();
            row = []
            bbox_temp = []
            filename = []
            try:
                filename.append(''.join([n for n in os.path.basename(item) if n.isdigit()]))
                bbox_temp.append(float(splited[1]))
                row.append(filename)
                row.append(bbox_temp)
                final_df.append(row)
            except:
                print("file is not in YOLO format!")   
                     
df = pd.DataFrame(final_df,columns=['filename','bbox'])

for col in ['filename','bbox']:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: next(iter(x)) if isinstance(x, list) else x)

df['filename'] = df['filename'].replace(
    to_replace=['00','01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23'], 
    value=['00:00-00:59', '01:00-01:59', '02:00-02:59', '03:00-03:59','04:00-04:59', '05:00-05:59', '06:00-06:59', '07:00-07:59','08:00-08:59', 
            '09:00-09:59', '10:00-10:59', '11:00-11:59','12:00-12:59','13:00-13:59','14:00-14:59','15:00-15:59','16:00-16:59','17:00-17:59','18:00-18:59',
            '19:00-19:59','20:00-20:59','21:00-21:59','22:00-22:59','23:00-23:59']) 

#remove duplicate    
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['filename','bbox'], keep='first')    
#Find max each text file
df = df.groupby(['filename']).agg({'bbox':'max'})     
        
# Export to csv
df.to_csv('C:\\Users\\xxx\\CountingCSV\\total_count.csv', sep='\t')
```

I got csv file as below. And I checked data space so weird.

[image]  [image]

so I want to separate data as below.

[image]

Please supporting me for separate .csv file column

for text file is yolo strong sort label file
[image]

I will use only blue highlight data and filename.

Comment: Is last row in ouput correct for `filename` column?

Comment: @Himanshu Poddar Do you have any idea. please recommend your code to me.

Comment: @jezreal oh sorry. last row will be (filename 6:00 - 6:59) and (bbox 1216)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC use:

```
df = df.assign(filename = df['filename'].str[:11], bbox= df['filename'].str[11:])
```

EDIT: For extract second column use:

```
import os

myFiles = glob.glob('C:\\Users\\xxx\\Sub_Folder\\*.txt')

dfs= ([pd.read_csv(fp, sep='\s+').iloc[:, [1]]
        .assign(f=os.path.basename(fp).split('.')[0])
        .set_axis(['bbox','filename'], axis=1)[['filename','bbox']] for fp in myFiles])
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for support. I try to use your code. I got error : KeyError: 'filename'. I don't know why . please supporting me.

Comment: @Kukkik So need only column with 3? Ouput csv is different.

Comment: Yes, only column with 3. This example text file. In the real work, It difference number.

Comment: @Kukkik - I see data `3`, not `03` so replace not working, also what is `bbox` ? What is logic for convert txt to csv?

Comment: In actually I want to get only that highlight column (in example is 3) and filename to make csv. file. If you have any idea to change my code or make new one. you can recommend it to me.

Comment: @Kukkik - added to answer, part `EDIT`

Comment: I'm so sorry. I got 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'read_csv'. I'd like to know. I can use your code for new code or use continues with my code. please recommend to me.

Comment: @Kukkik it is weird, because `myFiles = glob.glob('C:\\Users\\xxx\\Sub_Folder\\*.txt')` return filenames, so this error cannot raise (if use same variables)

Comment: I can change. If it better than one. Can I use listdir or scandir?

Comment: @Kukkik - Not understand, why cannot use `glob.glob` ?

Comment: I'm so sorry. First I use `glob.glob`. I will use `glob.glob`

Comment: I try to use your code. I got error 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'read_csv'.

Comment: @Kukkik - Do you understand error?

Comment: I try to find this error. I known after `read.csv` should follow by path of file. And your code already use function `for item in myFiles`  I think I don't understand now. please suggest to me.

Comment: @Kukkik - It was my typo, need `pd.read_csv` instead `df.read_csv`. Answer was edited.

Comment: @jezrael Oh! It is almost to work. Now I got filename column and bbox column. But only filename is full of path (C:\Users\xxx\05.txt). please suggest to me for changing from fullpath to only 05.

Comment: @jezrael Thank you very much. I got error : positional indexers are out-of-bounds.

Comment: @Kukkik - so separator in txt is not space?

Comment: @Kukkik - is possible some file has only one column? If yes it raisse error

Comment: @jezrael After I checked text files. Every text file same column as my picture example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246141/discussion-between-jezrael-and-kukkik).